# device-tree config for netdev trigger-sources to control LED based on link-status

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

### What would I like to achieve?

A GPIO connected LED should be

- ON if the interface's link is UP and
- OFF if the link is DOWN.

Configure this logic via the device-tree.

### Status-Quo : Functionality achieved with extra script

This is achievable with Kconfig's `CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_NETDEV=y`, a DTS entry, and
a small script in userspace.

```
leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";
        eth1_link {
                gpios = <&pioD 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
                default-state = "off";
                linux,default-trigger = "netdev";
        };
};


echo eth1 > /sys/class/leds/eth1_link/device_name
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/eth1_link/link
```

### Question : Isn't this already possible through the DTS?

The documentation from `Documentation/devicetree/bindings/leds/common.txt`, suggests
that this should be already available, but I cannot find a working example, and
what I have tried doesn't work so far.

> ```
> * Trigger source providers
>
> Each trigger source should be represented by a device tree node. It may be e.g.
> a USB port or an Ethernet device.
> ```

I tried adding `trigger-sources = <&macb1>;` with no success. (macb1 because of my board's config `arch/arm/boot/dts/sama5d3_emac.dtsi`)

As a kernel-newbie I ask myself what the action in kernel-dev-land would be?

Is sending such question to `linux-leds@vger.kernel.org` or `devicetree@vger.kernel.org` the thing to do or contact directly some maintainer?

===

#### UPDATE-1

I was missing a PHY node from the macb1 node. I re-tried with the phy node's phandle but didn't yet succeed. (But instead of the generic driver, the matching one is now selected.)

I will try further.

===

#### UPDATE-2

With the [link from 0audriy](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/phy/phy_led_triggers.c#L76) I could more-or-less backtrack where the phy gets registered:

```
phylink_of_phy_connect
  of_phy_attach
    phy_attach_direct
      phy_led_triggers_register
        phy_led_trigger_register
          led_trigger_register
```

Here there are 3 ways the code try to parse out the phy node:

```
    phy_node = of_parse_phandle(dn, "phy-handle", 0);
    if (!phy_node)
        phy_node = of_parse_phandle(dn, "phy", 0);
    if (!phy_node)
        phy_node = of_parse_phandle(dn, "phy-device", 0);
```

So I added the `phy-handle = <&phywan>;` attribute.
Still no success :/

I suppose for the micrel,ksz8081 this path is not even taken.

Maybe needs [porting from PHYLIB to PHYLINK](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/sfp-phylink.html)...

(Another solution which I am lamenting on, is to extend the micrel.c driver so that the link based IRQs can be turned on excusively and control the LED based on that interrupts...)

Comment: According to the code `macb` driver registers PHY and that, if device node is defined, will register the LED trigger. That said, you have to specify the name of the phy device as trigger

Comment: @0andriy thank you for helping! I was missing the PHY node.

Comment: @0andriy Did you reference the code in `of_mdio.c` ? 
`if (of_mdiobus_child_is_phy(child))      
 rc = of_mdiobus_register_phy(mdio, child, addr);`

I do not see, where the trigger registration is taking place...

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/phy/phy_led_triggers.c#L76

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose that is only available through phylink and not phylib :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally:

A last search for 'phy' in xconfig revealed the right setting: **`CONFIG_LED_TRIGGER_PHY=y`**

With that various trigger options are added to the led:

```
cat /sys/class/leds/eth1_link/trigger
none fixed-0:00:link fixed-0:00:100Mbps [f802c000.ethernet-ffffffff:00:link] f802c000.ethernet-ffffffff:00:100Mbps f802c000.ethernet-ffffffff:00:10Mbps timer heartbeat gpio netdev dsa-0.0:00:link dsa-0.0:00:100Mbps dsa-0.0:00:10Mbps dsa-0.0:01:link dsa-0.0:01:100Mbps dsa-0.0:01:10Mbps
```

And with a device tree entry:

```
leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";
        eth1_link {
                gpios = <&pioD 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
                default-state = "off";
                linux,default-trigger = "f802c000.ethernet-ffffffff:00:link";
        };
};
```

Exactly my desired logic can be configured, without any user-space scripts. (and kernel source changes.)

It may be just my perception, but I think the "netdev" based solution was also slower. Now with `ip link set down/up dev X` the SW and the HW controlled LEDs doesn't have a disturbingly big delay between them.